# Why in visual studio 2013 express, I don't have a project template Windows Control Library?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If it's not exist in the express version, is there any other way to make Windows Control Library ?

This is what I see when trying to make a new project:

[image: Windows Control]

Comment: Do you mean Windows Forms Control Library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean as in a COM .ocx file, that's not how .net works. You might even have to get Visual Studio 6 installed to do that, although I suppose check out the other project types. It's also possible there are other project types that are not installed by default, so try re-running the VS installer and see what else is available.

For a .net controls library you should create a class library and add your forms to it. VS will add the necessary references for you, and you can then reference that assembly from any other managed code.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual C# Express Edition, according to this :

[Windows Control Library: Missing Windows Control Library Template](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ef185ed-3811-462a-be02-87d1e31960c6/windows-control-library-missing-windows-control-library-template?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

**Windows Control Library Template should be same as : *Class Library project template***

But with added reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.

[image]

**I found another trick to create this missing template for visual studio 2013 Express**, With the help from this link:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21844-How-add-windows-control-library-template.aspx

So the steps for C# express 2013 are nearly the same than in the example witch is about c# 2005

1. Open Visual C# Express 2013.
2. Create New windows Application with the name: MyLibrary

[image]

3. From the Project menu select Add User Control. Click on Add

[image]

4. Close any forms windows.

(a view with the **Form** already closed)
[image]

5. In Solution Explorer, Delete forms related files

(the corresponding .cs files should be deleted by this step) 
[image]

6. From the Project menu select MyLibrary Properties.
7. In the Application tab set the Output Type to Class Library.

[image]

8. In the file Program.cs replace

**Application.Run(Form1)**

with

**Application.Run()**

9. Build the Solution. There should be no errors and the bin/Release folder should have a MyLibrary.dll file (i found it in Debug in my case)

[image]

10. From the File menu select Export Template.
11. Select Project Template then Next .
12. Under Template Options change the name of the template to Windows Control Library and the Description to Create windows Control .dll. Click on Finish.

[image]

12. Close C# Express 2013.

The next time you open Visual C# Express, you will find your newly created template ready to use.

[image]